# missing required positional arguments: Python: self

Tags: python, list, function, self

Getting an error :

```
TypeError: _get_request() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'id_list', 'id_item', 'to_be_sent', 'open', 'received', and 'sent'
```

When I am trying to call the function:

```
def _get_request(self, id: str,
                           id_list: List[str],
                           id_item: List[int],
                           to_be_sent: List[int],
                           open: List[int],
                           received: List[int],
                           sent: List[int]):



    return {
            'id': user_id,
            'num_results': 3,
            'id_list': uniqueVisitId,
            'id_item': id_item,
            'to_be_sent': need_to_be_sent,
            'open': open,
            'received': received,
            'sent': sent
    }
```

By:

```
self._get_request(
          {
           'id': 'x',
            'id_list': ['a', 'x'],
            'id_item': [1, 2],
            'to_be_sent': [1, 0],
            'open': [0, 0],
            'received': [0, 0],
            'sent': [0, 0]
          }
     )
```

Any guess why my function cant recognize the positionial arguments which I am passing over?

Comment: If you put `**` before your dictionary in the call, that might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing a dictionary and not arguments...

You should pass the arguments in order without Dict syntax:

```
self._get_request('x', ['a', 'x'], [1, 2],  [1, 0],   [0, 0],[0, 0], [0, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `**` before the dict items to parse them as key=value in functions

```py
def foo(*, a, b):
    return a, b


dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(foo(dict)) # -> missing
print(foo(**dict)) # -> returns (1, 2)
```

Comment: @adirabargil Dont say anything if you're bad at this
[code](https://prnt.sc/usneex)
[errors](https://prnt.sc/usnekq)

Comment: @Ozballer31 I think he meant the * in the definition of foo.

Comment: @Sarol He posted an answer there that said that you can't pass dict in functions, so I think he meant `**`

Comment: @Ozballer31 The specific quote is "Because you are passing a dictionary and not arguments..." which is, in this case, true. The OP passed in a dictionary without unpacking it, and adir stated that that was incorrect and showed how to do it just through positional arguments. There was nothing said about unpacking dictionaries being impossible in general

Comment: Lol i even voted you up man, be polite... we are competing to help people :)...

Answer (score 1):

You are passing it only one argument — a dictionary. If you are just writing specific calls to get_request(), and/or the dictionary will always have that set of specified keys, do what adir said. If the dictionary you are passing it comes from somewhere else and may have varying keywords. then you can use dictionary unpacking like this:

```
# Assigning it just for the example, might be the result from a function or whatever you're doing
request_info_dict = {
                     'id': 'x',
                     'id_list': ['a', 'x'],
                     'id_item': [1, 2],
                     'to_be_sent': [1, 0],
                     'open': [0, 0],
                     'received': [0, 0],
                     'sent': [0, 0]
                   }
self._get_request(**request_info_dict)
```